# Conditionally Checking for Errors with Formik Field Component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, formik

I have set up the following form using `Formik`:

```
const RenderForm = ({ errors, isSubmitting, isValid, touched }) => {
  return (
    <Form>
      <h3>Sign Up</h3>
      <Email
        name="email"
        error={touched.email && errors.email ? 'error' : null}
      />
      <Password
        name="password"
        error={touched.password && errors.password ? 'error' : null}
      />
      <Button disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting} type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
      {/* {errors.firebaseErrorMessage && ( */}
      {/* <Help>{errors.firebaseErrorMessage}</Help> */}
      {/* )} */}
    </Form>
  )
}
```

The `Email` component and the `Password` components are just wrappers for the Formik `Field` Component.  I want to be able to add a red border a particular field if it fails validation.

To do that, I have set up a conditional for the `error` prop.  IF it is touched AND IF the error is passed, then it renders that prop with a value of 'error'.

Now there are a few problems with this.

FIRST PROBLEM
I don't need to render a value of 'error' (or any other value) to the `error` attribute.  I just need to have the attribute 'error' itself (without any value) and then it will be styled appropriately.

SECOND PROBLEM

It's a bit annoying to write out the same conditional test for each field.  I would like to know if there is something like the `ErrorMessage` component, except for a prop.  Basically, something like this:

```
<Email name="email" errorProp />
<Password name="password" errorProp />
```

The idea being that `errorProp` will set an attribute of 'error' if an error exists and nothing if an error does not exist.

So here is my question...

How can I create my own `errorProp` or, at the very least, simplify what I am trying to do?

Thanks.